# anychart 8.2.0 causes "Namespace has no exported member 'DataGridButton'" error in Angular4 npm start build

Tags: angular, npm, anychart

My Angular 4 project was using anychart 8.1.0, and upon building a clean install, anychart 8.2.0 got grabbed. When I ran `npm start` I got the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/anychart/dist/index.d.ts: Namespace 'anychart.core.ui' has no exported member 'DataGridButton'.

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Are there additional steps I need to do to get 8.2.0 to work? Or should I require 8.1.0 in my package.json file? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team has prepared a dev-preview of 8.2.1 update and you can try it in your projects. This update includes many bug fixes of index.d.ts.
To get this update replace in ‘package.json’ the current AnyChart dependence with the following  "anychart": "8.2.1-rc.0"
Or you can download it manually via NPM: $ npm install anychart@8.2.1-rc.0
Very soon our team will provide public release of 8.2.1 update.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is already known. Unfortunately, the current version of index.d.ts file 8.2.0 requires some fixes to compile the project without errors and warnings. By the end of this week, we are going to release 8.2.1 version of index.d.ts which will include many bugfixes. I will notify you when the fix becomes available.
Until that we recommend to use 8.1.0 version.

Comment: Thank you! Looking forward to it!

Comment: Our team has released a public 8.2.1 update and you can try it in your projects. This update includes many bug fixes of index.d.ts.
To get this update execute 'npm update' or replace in 'package.json' the current AnyChart dependence with the following "anychart": "8.2.1"
Or you can download it manually via NPM: $ npm install anychart@8.2.1